# Keep getting complimation errors in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Let’s suppose that Acme Corporation has Anvil building operations in six distinct locations in Texas – Houston (row index 0), Dallas (row index 1), Huntsville (row index 2), San Antonio (row index 3), Waco (row index 4) and Humble (row index 5). In each location, they manufacture 8 different Anvil Models. They have collected the “sales” data of these 8 models in each of its 6 different locations for the year 2014 and saved it in an array. Let us first create an array called sales using the statement below:

int[][] sales = new int[6][8];

Let us now populate the array sales with random numbers. Generate random numbers that are between 0 and 25 and store it in the array.

Now, accomplish the following tasks:

a.  Write code to compute and print the total number of anvils sold at each location.
b.  Acme would like to determine their least popular anvil model. Assuming that a model is unpopular if it has been sold in only 3 cities or fewer, write code to print a list of all the models that are unpopular. 
c.  Which location has the most hardworking employees. That is, which location has sold the most anvils.
d.  Which location has sold the least anvils.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

int[][] sales = new int[6][8];



int sum=0;
for (int row=0; row<6;row++){

for(int col=0; col<8; col++){
  sum=sum+sales[row][col];
  System.out.println("The total is:" + sum);

public static String determineLocation(int row){
String name= " ";

if (row == 0){
 name= "Houston";

 else if (row==1){
  name="Dallas";

  else if (row== 2){
  name="Huntsville";

 else if (row== 3){
 name="San Antonio";

 else if( row == 4){
 name= "Waco";

 else if (row==5){
 name="Humble";

 return name;


  public static void unpopular(int[][] sales){
int count=0;
for (int row=0; row<6;row++){

for(int col=0; col<8; col++){
    if(sales[row][col]<3){
                count++;
    }
    System.out.println("unpopular model are:"+ count);
}


     public static void mostSales(int[][]sales){

   int min;
    for(int i=1 ;i<8; i++){
         if( sales.length <min){

              }
           System.out.println(min + "Sold the least anvils");


  public static void leastSales(int[][] sales){

int max;

for(int i=1 ;i<6; i++){
   if(sales.length>max){

   System.out.println(max + "Sold the most anvils");
```

Comment: would you like to share some of your code with us? and not just the assigment?

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, not a programmers-for-hire site.  I think you were looking for the latter.

Comment: Im sorry I just learned how to add my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int[][] sales = new int[6][8];

    // a
    for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sales[i].length; j++) {
            sum += j;
        }
        System.out.println("Location " + String.valueOf(i) + " has "
                + String.valueOf(sum) + " anvils sold");
    }

    // b
    for (int i = 0; i < sales[0].length; i++) {
        int unpopular = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sales.length; j++) {
            if (sales[j][i] > 0) {
                unpopular++;
            }
            if (unpopular >= 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (unpopular < 3) {
            System.out.println("Modle " + String.valueOf(i)
                    + " is un popular");
        }
    }

    // c3
    int max = -1;
    int maxLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sales[i].length; j++) {
            sum += j;
        }
        if (sum > max) {
            max = sum;
            maxLocation = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Location " + String.valueOf(maxLocation)
            + " has most hardworking employees");

    // d
    int min = 25 * 8 + 1;
    ;
    int minLocation = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sales[i].length; j++) {
            sum += j;
        }
        if (sum < min) {
            min = sum;
            minLocation = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Location " + String.valueOf(minLocation)
            + " has most hardworking employees");
```